# Is there a way to separate the rows of table in multiples machines (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, clustering

I have a application (Postgres) where there are a lot of rows (over millions) and I have to make a lot of INSERTs and SELECTs at the same time. And I'm thinking to make a cluster of machines. I tried pgpool2, but this architecture is not what I want. I want to divide the rows of my tables in the other machines, so I can balance the data and have more performance. If is this possible, is there a software or a way to do this? Or do I just go back to pgpool2 or use the cluster of Postgres in the same machine?

Comment: The keyworkd for what you are searching for is "sharding". That is splitting the database content over multiple servers running at the same time with some system/tool/library that splits data based on some criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a cluster with master for writes and standbys for read. You may also want [pg_bouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/).